# Apex test code problem with relationships?

Tags: apex

I have a test code that im trying to implement,
And I need to create an Account, Contact, and Contract.

And I'm getting the relationships wrong

Here is the test code

```
@isTest 
private class Send_noti_emailsTestClass2 {

    static testMethod void validateSend_noti_emails2() {

       List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>{};



    Query_and_upload_Super_user myLicenseGenerator2 = new  Query_and_upload_Super_user();

    String insName = 'InstitName';
    Account a = new Account(Name =insName , Country__c='US');
      accounts.add(a);
      insert accounts;
    Account getAccountID = [SELECT ID FROM Account Where Name = :insName ];
    myLicenseGenerator2.aa= accounts;


    List<Contact> contact = new List<Contact>{};
     String emailAdd= 'stevemike@gmail.com';
    Contact c = new Contact(Email=emailAdd, LastName='Steve', AccountId = getAccountID.ID);
    contact.add(c); 
    insert contact;
    Contact getContactID = [SELECT Id, AccountId From Contact Where Email =:emailAdd];
     myLicenseGenerator2.ac= contact;



    Contract ee = new Contract(Host_Name__c ='HN' ,Volume_Serial_Number__c='VSN', Physical_Address__c ='IP',License_Type__c ='Temprary', StartDate =Date.today(),Expiration_Date__c=Date.today(), CustomerSignedId=getContactID.Id, AccountId=getAccountID.ID);
    insert ee;
    myLicenseGenerator2.contract= ee;


    Inquery__c inq = new Inquery__c(First_Name__c='Steve', Last_Name__c='Mike',Email__c='stevemike@gmail.com', Institution__c = 'InstitName', Position__c ='IT' ,Quilification__c='Qualified', Previous_user__c= true);
    insert inq ;
    myLicenseGenerator2.inquery= inq;    
myLicenseGenerator2.save();

}
}
```

The code fails in the APEX code:

Here is a small portion of the code:

```
public with sharing class Query_and_upload_Super_user {

   public Inquery__c inquery{get;set;}

   public List<Inquery__c > u {get;set;}
    public Contract contract{get;set;}
   public Contact ac{get;set;}

   public List<Contract> myCon{get;set;}


    public Query_and_upload_Super_user(){
    inquery = new Inquery__c()
    u         = new List<Inquery__c >();
    ac         = new List<Contact>();     
        Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');


     public PageReference save() {
     string user_query = '';

        myCon = new List<Contract>();

    u  = [select Name, Last_Name__c,  Acquire_license__c, Final_Email_Date__c, First_Name__c,Previous_user__c,Quilification__c,email__c,Country__c,Institution__c from Inquery__c where email__c=:inquery.email__c ];


    if(u.size() >0){
     ac = [Select Id, AccountId From Contact Where Email =:record.Email__c];

    myCon = [Select License_Type__c,Host_Name__c,Volume_Serial_Number__c, CustomerSignedId, StartDate, Expiration_Date__c,Physical_Address__c  From Contract WHERE CustomerSignedId =:ac.get(0).Id];  

                 Contract reccon = myCon[0];
    return null;
 }
 }
```

So myCon is null

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with relationships above?

Comment: Are you getting an error upon running this code or are you not finding that the relationships are set when querying the objects back out?

Comment: What's the problem with the relationships? How is this particular code not working for you?

Comment: It fails when i try to query a Contract based on the Contact ID as follows:   Contact[] ac = [Select Id, AccountId From Contact Where Email =:record.Email__c]; MyCon = [Select License_Type__c,Host_Name__c,Volume_Serial_Number__c, CustomerSignedId, StartDate, Expiration_Date__c,Physical_Address__c  From Contract WHERE CustomerSignedId =:ac.get(0).Id];  So myCon is null

Comment: Please add the code to the question along with your findings when running your queries

Comment: Contract field `CustomerSignedId` is not established in your test data. Do you have some trigger on Contract insert that copies over a contactId and adds to the Contract SObject instance?

Comment: Post the code that you are trying to test.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the test code, and the location where the code fails,

Comment: Its a very long code,

Comment: I have added a portion of the code, where the problem happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the code, and edited the code above,
I hope this others,

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on which steps you took to troubleshoot your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a logic problem in your code.

u is always null in your construct, because your query for `Inquery__c` records with `email__c=:inquery.email__c` . But `inquery.email__c` is always null because it has not been initialized. That is why u is NULL, so you never pass in your following if condition.

You have probably forgotten to do something with your id parameter : this is initialized with `getParameters()` but not used.  If it is a Contact id, I suppose you need to query for that Contact, then assign `inquery.email__c=ctct.Email` : this is only a guess from what you are testing for.

I hope this helps you fix your logic.

Comment: Well i have another APEX code that has that similar part, and mt test code works with it. The difference is that the other code i dont need to create an Account, Contact, and Contract. SO thats why i think the code fails because of my query relationships in the test code. Does everyone think that part is correct?

Comment: The inquery.email__c is taken from the Visual Force page, so the Id takes care of that part.

Comment: I just debugged the APEX code, and the ac.get(0).Id has a value or Id, but its not Correct, so myCon size is zero. So i think im positive at this point that i have not setup the relationships correct in the text code.